# Convert array to list of blank variables for function parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

If you take a look at my code below you can see i have a organised array of models, collections and view. I have a function called includes thats concatenates all values from that object into one single array.

This is just me being a neat-freak...but some how some way need to generate the list of params in on the second require argument.

Here is my code.

```js
var files = {
   models : [
      'Models/BlogPost',
      'Models/Tweet'
   ],
   collections : [
      'Collections/BlogPosts',
      'Collections/Tweets'
   ],
   views : [
      'Views/BlogPostIndexView',
      'Views/TwitterView'
   ],
};

var includes = function() {
   return files.models.concat(files.collections,files.views);
}

require(includes, function(BlogPost, BlogPosts, BlogPostIndexView,    Tweet, Tweets, TwitterView){ ... }
```

Ideally I want my require method to look as follows...

```js
require(includes, function(function(){return getParams()}));
```

Answer (score 0):

`BlogPost, BlogPosts, BlogPostIndexView, Tweet, Tweets, TwitterView` are `names` of arguments. AFAIK You cannot really put them in a variable or function and return them.

What you can do is, you can use `arguments` to access them inside your function.

So your code will look like

```
require(includes, function(){
    var BlogPost = arguments[0],
        BlogPosts = arguments[1];
       ...
});
```

This might address your love of neatness but I don't know if it is what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Why not this:

```
var params = {
    BlogPost: BlogPost,
    BlogPosts: BlogPosts,
    BlogPostIndexView: BlogPostIndexView,
    Tweet: Tweet,
    Tweets: Tweets,
    TwitterView: TwitterView
}

require(includes, function(params){ ... }
```

?

### EDIT

```
var params = [BlogPost, BlogPosts, BlogPostIndexView, Tweet, Tweets, TwitterView];

require(includes, function(params){ ... }
```

Comment: Because thats an object - where as i am try to define a set of params dynamically ?

Comment: I don't think you understand what it is i am trying to achieve here

Comment: Not really, can you explain it better?